# Hide tabs in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css, master-page

I have found how to hide the first top nav tab, but I need to hide the last one as well. Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try hiding them using CSS.

`

```
(function()
{
  document.querySelector("#pageContentTitle").style.display = 'none';
})();
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a :nth-last-child(2) selector. For example:

```
.static:nth-last-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```